# vtiger crm : single csv file to multiple database table

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, vtiger

I'm trying to create a php script and add it with vTiger crm, this script will add to vTiger the functionality to add a single csv file to a multiple database tables.

I don't know how can i add this script to vTiger

Any suggestions, Documentation, Help ?

I am working with Vtiger CRM version 6.0

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this.
The first one is register a new module in your CRM, (searching google for the Payslip example module).
Broadly, a vtiger Module is structured in two parts, the first in PHP that you using to process all your data, your functions, the second is passing what you had processed into the Smarty Template engine.

About the main methods, consider that vtiger generally pass 2 URL parameters:
"module", is used to retrive the module name -> directory -> privileges and all the rest
"action", is used to call a specific php file into the module.
In all this you should consider the implementation of the all the basic vtiger framework, controls, privileges, ecc.

About the database, Vtiger use the adb method.
Take a look to the include/database/PearDatabase.php for a comprehensive overview of all the database functions.

A second way, highly raccomended, is process your CSV file using the vtiger Webservice https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Webservices_tutorials
and so, use an external PHP file.
This way is more less flexibile, but you can workaround all the basic implementation and focus on the data.